# What is the difference between initializing instance variables in & out of a constructor?

Tags: d

In the following code sample, `milk` is initialized by a constructor, and `egg` isn't. `milk.spill()` does not segfault, but `egg.crack()` does. What is the difference between the two ways of initialzing an instance variable? Why is the former correct while the latter causes segfaults?

```d
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  auto k = new Kitchen();
  k.pollute();
}

class Kitchen {
  Milk milk;
  Egg egg = new Egg();

  this() {
    milk = new Milk();
  }

  void pollute() {
    writeln("spilling milk");
    milk.spill();
    writeln("cracking egg");
    egg.crack();
  }
}

class Milk {
  bool spilt = false;
  void spill() { spilt = true; }
}

class Egg {
  bool cracked = false;
  void crack() { cracked = true; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you provided the correct example? It works. Maybe you meant to remove the «= new Egg();» part?

Comment: egg.crack should not have segfaulted there, and doesn't for me. There is a difference between the two lines, an important difference that confuses people, and I can write that up, but your example code works for me. Does it segfault for you too or is this an excerpt from a bigger thing?

Comment: I once had this issue too. How community explained it all to me: http://forum.dlang.org/post/rzbhwpjgxrvhmoirrgwg@forum.dlang.org

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe , yes, this code consistently segfaults when compiled with GDC 5.2.1 . Because you said it doesn't segfault for you, I've tried it again with LDC 0.14.0 , and it did run without segfaulting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the difference between the two ways is when the code is run. When you initialize in a constructor, the code is run at runtime, when each new object is made. When you do it directly on the class member, the object is actually constructed at compile time and referenced statically.

What that means in your example is that there's a new Milk object created for each Kitchen object. When you run `new Kitchen`, the constructor runs, meaning you get a `new Milk` as well.

`Egg` is different. It is in a static context, so that initializer is run at compile time - only once. What that means is that there is only *one* `Egg` shared among all the `new Kitchen`s. The variable itself isn't static, if you assigned it to a `new Egg` sometime after making a `new Kitchen`, it would only affect that instance of the kitchen, but the object it refers to immediately *is*.

So if you just set it to `new Egg` outside the constructor and never replace it, any modifications you do to that egg will be visible across all instances of the kitchen - after you crack the egg, then do another `new Kitchen`, it will already have a cracked egg!